# How to send the shipping email to multiple customer in Netsuite

Tags: netsuite

I created a saved search that will search the sales order of every each customer and email the shipment status to tracking email created in SO field.
But it can be only 1 email I input to the field.

How can I send the email to multiple tracking emails .

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a standard Saved Search that sends an email, you can edit this on the search itself. If they are static email addresses of a contact or a user in NetSuite (Specific Recipients), you can add them this way:

[image: Specific Recipients]

If you need to derive the users from the results, you can add them this way:

[image: Recipients from Results]

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I created a field for email and set up to "Recipients from Results",
but my question is how can I set 2 or more email to the field, so that I can Schedulely sent the search result to multiple emails?

Comment: I might be misunderstanding your question but you should be able to add more lines to the sublist by adding other contacts or employees. You will need an active contact or employee for each one that you wish to send an email to.

Answer (score 0):

One no-code way would be to replace the transaction's email address with an alias that forwards to some list of email addresses. A bit hacky in that you have to maintain the forwarding addresses independently of the customer (unless you code that)

The methods in the answer by @GimmeDatPP should work if you have contacts. You'd have to supress the normal send email flag on the item fulfillments.

finally this can be done by scripting the process and pulling the email addresses from a custom list on the customer or transaction.